# Programmatically add tab to tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an app with a `UITabBarController` as my initial view controller.

Currently I'm doing everything in Storyboard but I want to programmatically add a tab to the tab bar based on a user being logged in or not.

I made a `TestViewController` to test this out. Right now I have two tabs (pictured below). I want to have a third tab positioned on the right programmatically. I put this code in my AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunching` method. Based on print statements the view controller is being added to the tab bar but it is not appearing in the tab bar then the app loads.

Any suggestions?

```
    func addTabTEST() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootTabController") as! UITabBarController
    let TestVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController") as! TestViewController
    let icon = UITabBarItem(title: "test", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
    TestVC.tabBarItem = icon

    print("TAB CONTROLLERS 1: \(tabController.viewControllers)")

    tabController.addChildViewController(TestVC)
    tabController.viewControllers![2] = TestVC

    print("TAB CONTROLLERS 2: \(tabController.viewControllers)")

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let nav1 = UINavigationController()
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let first: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    nav1.viewControllers = [first]
    nav1.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    nav1.title = "first"

    let nav2 = UINavigationController()
    let second: SecondViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    nav2.viewControllers = [second]
    nav2.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    nav2.title = "second"

    let nav3 = UINavigationController()
    let third: ThirdViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
    nav3.viewControllers = [third]
    nav3.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    nav3.title = "third"



    let tabController = UITabBarController()
    tabController.viewControllers = [nav1,nav2,nav3]
    tabController.selectedIndex = 0

    self.window!.rootViewController = tabController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

**this is for swift 4**

`self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`

```
    let first = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    nav1.viewControllers = [first]
    nav1.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    nav1.title = "first"

    let nav2 = UINavigationController()
    let second: HomeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController2") as! HomeViewController2
    nav2.viewControllers = [second]
    nav2.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    nav2.title = "second"

    let nav3 = UINavigationController()
    let third = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController3") as! HomeViewController3
    nav3.viewControllers = [third]
    nav3.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    nav3.title = "third"



    let tabController = UITabBarController()
    tabController.viewControllers = [nav1,nav2,nav3]
    tabController.selectedIndex = 0

    self.window!.rootViewController = tabController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use `UIStoryboard` and if you have three view controllers named `oneVC`, `twoVC`, and `threeVC` you can use (works on Swift 5.3 with iOS 14.2)

```
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.window = window

        // Put image path if you want to have an image on your TabBar for this view controller
        self.oneVC?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "One", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        self.twoVC?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Two", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        self.threeVC?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Three", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)

        let tabController = UITabBarController()
        tabController.viewControllers = [oneVC, twoVC, threeVC]
        tabController.selectedIndex = 0

        self.window!.rootViewController = tabController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```